# Nully the null error

Tags: c#, xna

Is there a way to tell the program that i don't care if a class reference is null.
For example:

```
if (playermove[i].name == "punch" || ispunchactivated == true)
{
    Do the punch;
}
```

Why is he searching for the playermove (that can be null) and give me a null exeption error? i really don't care if the ispunchactivated is true.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this,

```
if ((ispunchactivated == true) || (playermove[i] != null && playermove[i].name == "punch" ))
{
    Do the punch;
}
```

Comment: You were the first to answer, so answer for you and one point for all the nice people over there.

Answer (score 9):

If you put your two conditions the other way around:

```
ispunchactivated /*== true*/ || playermove[i].name == "punch"
                 // this isn't necessary
```

then, if the first one is true, the second one won't be checked.

However, unless you *know* `playermove[i]` won't be null if `ispunchactivated` is false, you should really be making the null check too, otherwise you'll still get exceptions:

```
ispunchactivated ||
    (playermove[i] != null && playermove[i].name == "punch")
```

Answer (score 4):

You just check it for null first.
There are not shortcuts here.

```
if (playermove == null || playermove[i].name == "punch" || ispunchactivated == true)
{
    Do the punch;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can modify the if condition as follows:

```
if (ispunchactivated == true || (playermove!=null && playermove[i].name == "punch" ))
```

Answer (score 2):

Just interchange the conditions and shortcircuitting will do that for you:

```
if (ispunchactivated == true || playermove[i].name == "punch")
{
    Do the punch;
}
```

`playermove[i]` is only evaluated if `ispunchactivated` is false. That being said, you can still run into a null pointer exception if `ispunchactivated` is false and `playermove[i]` is null.

Answer (score 1):

Change your condition as follows:

```
if(playermove !=null && playermove[i] != null)
{
    if (playermove[i].name == "punch" || ispunchactivated == true)
    {
        Do the punch;
    }
}
```